# Has anyone else noticed that IE 11 quit working with multi selects?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, forms, http-post

I am using the `<select name="field[]" multiple>` method of passing multiple values from a select box to php as array.  Has been working fine in IE. Started getting support calls today of problems in IE.  Still works fine in other browsers.

Anyone else seen this?  Guessing an IE auto-update broke this?

Comment: Just tested this in IE 11.0.9600.16428. Works fine for me

Comment: Phil - I'm showing 11.0.9600.16476 and Update Versions 11.0.2

Comment: Just updated to 11.0.9600.16476 (Update Version 11.0.2) and it still works as expected

Comment: Thanks for testing.  I tested a basic page and also had success.  On my production page, I've narrowed it down to a javascript error on a calendar plugin that is throwing an error.  For some reason that is what is preventing the current release of IE from submitting the multiple form values. I'm still working out the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tracked down the problem to a javascript error with a calendar popup that was giving an error of:
"unable to get property parentnode of undefined or null reference"
I added some code to prevent that error and now the multi-select field properly passes the values.

We did not change any code and the failure to submit the multi-select values seems to have started today, so I can only guess an IE auto-update changed IE to either start issuing the js error, or changed it so the multi-selects failed to submit when there was an error.